# Exists in other Rows on same table with duplicate field

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure as per:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `pk_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `field2` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Where `field1` will have duplicates. I am trying to query for all rows with `A` or `B` in `field2` in a specific month, where there exists on the same table row or rows with the same `field1` but with `Z` for `field2`. I have interpreted this as the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (field2='A' or field2='B') AND
MONTH(field3_date)=MONTH('2016-06-01') AND
EXISTS
    (
        SELECT field1 FROM table1 AS temp_table
        WHERE table1.field2='Z' AND table1.field1=temp_table.field1
    )
ORDER BY field3_date DESC;
```

I am not getting any rows returned though I have confirmed that numerous instances fulfill the conditions. I have also tried without `AND table1.field1=temp_table.field1` in my subquery and receive the same result. Any suggestions or indication on what could correct my query? Warm regards,

EDIT: Sample dummy data and expected output provided here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-dSXR_sK71ZSrzRpAsfm0VBEP9EDDKTtcMRXOeclwNs/edit?usp=sharing

2nd EDIT: Adding mock data in usable format:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`pk_id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3_date`)
VALUES
    (10000000000000000001, 'SFCAVLDLYCQQFPHB', 'A', '2016-06-01 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000002, 'BP3RJZCWQFXS32TS', 'B', '2016-06-02 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000003, 'PVR2HEA6VFXYVFVV', 'A', '2016-06-03 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000004, 'G7MDHGYVUUELJZCY', 'B', '2016-06-04 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000005, 'PVR2HEA6VFXYVFVV', 'Z', '2016-06-05 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000006, 'NC3KNPPGDH6JTCEW', 'A', '2016-06-06 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000007, '4TYFQNKSRYEJXABH', 'A', '2016-06-07 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000008, 'BP3RJZCWQFXS32TS', 'Z', '2016-06-08 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000009, 'EGUR5CUBYRQZ6286', 'B', '2016-06-09 00:00:00'),
    (10000000000000000010, 'SQWKPRYJEJDMZ8Y3', 'B', '2016-06-10 00:00:00')
;
```

Comment: Testable example plus expected output according to sample input data, please. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Added sample input data and expected output as per your request. Thank you in advance. Warm regards.

Comment: sqlfiddle qualifies as sample data and a tabular output here. That way people can cut and paste it into their environment, and run it.

Comment: @Drew not sure I understand your comment. Are you stating that I need to put the sample in sqlfiddle? Not familiar with this platform. I have used the DDL function and added the table definition and values to my OP. Please feel free to let me know if this is sufficient or any further changes required.

Comment: Well it may be helpful in the future for showing tabular expected results. So, expected results in a table visible in the question. No one is going to cut and paste that, just eyeball it. As for sqlfiddle, on the left side of the screen, one does all the create table statements followed by insert statements for the test data. And then shares the url. It doesn't matter so much if there is any query entered on the right side to test against. In that way, no one doubts the schema, and has test data available. Often, more advanced devs will pass by a question without it

Comment: So, at the moment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38468141), the first block is junk, but blocks 2 3 4 are great. What if he has 4 tables for the input? We just ignore the question and move on. Unless of course no one is expected to test anything before answering, and just throw spagetti at the wall, hoping for points.

Comment: @Drew Thank you for taking the time to explain how to better post mysql questions. I'm getting a `Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'pk_id' at row 1` error trying to "Build Schema" just using the "Text to DDL" utility so I won't be able to provide a link. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but will continue trying and if possible will add to my question.

Comment: no problem, just stuff to play with for the future. It makes people want to get involved with stuff. In the end, most people only care about the stuff in the upper left pane like here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb63ae/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table1 t2
ON     t2.field2 = 'Z' AND
       t2.field1 = t1.field1 AND
       t2.pk_id <> t1.pk_id
WHERE t1.field2 IN ('A', 'B') AND
      MONTH(t1.field3_date)=MONTH('2016-06-01')
```

`t1` is your original table; `t2` is your duplicate. The comparison of `t1.pk_id` and `t2.pk_id` ensures that `t1` does not join to itself. Actually, this comparison is not strictly required (because `t2.field2` will be 'Z' and `t1.field2` will be 'A' or 'B', but it's a good safeguard if you want to modify your query with different selection criteria later.

Comment: I quickly tried this while experimenting with sqlfiddle.com and got 0 rows back with the mock data. Is `t1` and `t2` default acronyms for tables? Or are this aliases I need to create prior to running the query? Also I would rather not clone the full table as it is fairly big.

Comment: Actually retried it and it worked as expected though it gave me the "Z" rows. Changing the first `t2` to `t1` resolved this though. I think I get that on those very lines you are settings `t1` and `t2` as aliases which was something that was confusing me. Marking as correct answer. Thank you

Comment: Oops, yeah sorry. I hadn't tried it with your sql fiddle and was a bit confused as to exactly what you wanted since the question was a tad abstract. Good to see you got it working though!