# mySQL is not selecting the values of the row with the MAX date

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:

```
SYMBOL     | TRADE_DATE | LAST_10_DAYS
----------------------------------
ADI        | 2016-01-08 | NULL
ADI        | 2016-01-07 | NULL
ADI        | 2016-01-06 | NULL
ADI        | 2016-01-05 | NULL
ADI        | 2016-01-04 | NULL
ADI        | 2015-07-06 | 4.5
```

I then wrote the following query to try and get the value in the LAST_10_DAYS column for the MAX date:

```
SELECT SYMBOL, MAX(TRADE_DATE) as MAX_DATE, LAST_10_DAYS 
FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE 
WHERE SYMBOL='ADI' 
GROUP BY SYMBOL
```

When I do this I would expect the following output:

```
SYMBOL     | TRADE_DATE | LAST_10_DAYS
----------------------------------
ADI        | 2016-01-08 | NULL
```

However, I get the following output:

```
SYMBOL     | TRADE_DATE | LAST_10_DAYS
----------------------------------
ADI        | 2016-01-08 | 4.5
```

Why would this be happening?

EDIT: This is within a JOIN but that part wasn't working. Here is the full query:

```
 SELECT AR_SQ.SYMBOL, AR_SQ.NAME, AR_SQ.LAST, FF_PS.SECTOR, FF_PS.SECTOR_TAGS, RS.LAST_10_DAYS, RS.YTD_PERF, RS.MaxDate 
 FROM AR_STOCK_QUOTE AR_SQ 
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT HP.SYMBOL, max(TRADE_DATE) as MaxDate, HP.LAST_10_DAYS, HP.YTD_PERF 
 FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE HP 
 GROUP BY HP.SYMBOL 
 ) RS on RS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL 
 JOIN FF_PRIMARY_STOCK_TABLE FF_PS on FF_PS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL 
 WHERE RS.SYMBOL = 'ADI'
```

Comment: Are you always filtering `RS.SYMBOL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions don't work how you are thinking they work. `MAX()` doesn't select the row where the max value occurs. It returns the greatest *value* from the named column. This value might occur on every row!

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT SYMBOL, 
  MAX(TRADE_DATE) as MAX_DATE, 
  MIN(TRADE_DATE) as MIN_DATE, 
  AVG(TRADE_DATE) as AVG_DATE, 
  LAST_10_DAYS 
FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE 
WHERE SYMBOL='ADI' 
GROUP BY SYMBOL
```

From which row in each group should MySQL take the value of `LAST_10_DAYS`? The row that has the greatest date? The row that has the lowest date? What if more than one row is tied for the greatest date, i.e. two or more rows have the same date, but different values for `LAST_10_DAYS`?

What about the AVG_DATE? Perhaps the average date doesn't occur on any row in the table. What then do you expect to be the value of `LAST_10_DAYS`?

What you are trying to get is not only the max value, but the row where that value occurs.

```
SELECT AR_SQ.SYMBOL, AR_SQ.NAME, AR_SQ.LAST, FF_PS.SECTOR,
  FF_PS.SECTOR_TAGS, RS.LAST_10_DAYS, RS.YTD_PERF, RS.TRADE_DATE 
FROM AR_STOCK_QUOTE AR_SQ 
INNER JOIN FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE RS
  ON RS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL
INNER JOIN (
  SYMBOL, MAX(TRADE_DATE) AS TRADE_DATE
  FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE
  GROUP BY SYMBOL 
) MAXRS 
  ON RS.SYMBOL = MAXRS.SYMBOL AND RS.TRADE_DATE = MAXRS.TRADE_DATE
JOIN FF_PRIMARY_STOCK_TABLE FF_PS on FF_PS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL 
WHERE RS.SYMBOL = 'ADI'
```

The subquery returns the symbols, and the max trade date for each symbol. Then you need to join that value to the stock price table again, to find the row where that date occurs. Then you can get other columns from that row.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm trying to get the row that has the max date in it. Is this achievable or not really?

Comment: See example I added above.

Comment: Worked great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as your sub-query:

```
SELECT SYMBOL, TRADE_DATE as MAX_DATE, LAST_10_DAYS, YTD_PERF  
FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE 
WHERE SYMBOL='ADI' 
ORDER BY TRADE_DATE DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Since you are filtering `SYMBOL`, this is faster than the aggregate approach which finds the max date for all `SYMBOL`s.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a condition

```
  SELECT SYMBOL, TRADE_DATE , LAST_10_DAYS 
  FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE 
  WHERE SYMBOL='ADI' 
  AND trade_date = (select MAX(TRADE_DATE)  FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE   )
```

for the full query you can use this (with a proper group by

```
 SELECT AR_SQ.SYMBOL, AR_SQ.NAME, AR_SQ.LAST, FF_PS.SECTOR, FF_PS.SECTOR_TAGS, RS.LAST_10_DAYS, RS.YTD_PERF, RS.MaxDate 
 FROM AR_STOCK_QUOTE AR_SQ 
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT HP.SYMBOL, max(TRADE_DATE) as MaxDate
 FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE HP 
 GROUP BY HP.SYMBOL 
 ) RS on RS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL 
 INNER JOIN FF_PRIMARY_STOCK_TABLE FF_PS on FF_PS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL 
 WHERE RS.SYMBOL = 'ADI'
```

Comment: I already had it in a sub query but was trying to show this first since it wasn't work. Please see the updated question for the full query. Question updated.